# How to use array with ejs with html tags

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like so:

```
["Object1","Object2","Object3"]
```

I'd like to use this array to iterate over the objects to  fill out this html format like so:

```
  <option data-img-src=OBJECT 1 value="1"></option>
  <option data-img-src=OBJECT 2 value="2"></option>
  <option data-img-src=OBJECT 3 value="3"></option>
```

I'd like to also need to get the `value` for each object.

So for first one would be `value="1"` and so on counting up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inside Express/EJS templates, what is cleanest way to loop through an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16153384/inside-express-ejs-templates-what-is-cleanest-way-to-loop-through-an-array)

Comment: Duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

---

You can use JavaScript to create and append DOM elements to HTML.

```js
var obj= ["Object1","Object2","Object3"];
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    opt = document.createElement("OPTION");
    opt.setAttribute('data-img-src',obj[i]);
    opt.setAttribute('value',i+1);
    document.body.appendChild(opt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for ejs 
var obj= ["Object1","Object2","Object3"];// assuming this is the object

foreach can be used

```
<% obj.forEach(function(val,index) { %>
                 <option data-img-src=<%= val %> value=<%= (index+1) %>></option>
 <% }); %>
```